# How to provide a visual breakdown of the liquor category (by Category Name)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I did use the code below to upload data on r

```
if (!file.exists("ames-liquor.rds")) {
  url <- "https://github.com/ds202-at-ISU/materials/blob/master/03_tidyverse/data/ames-liquor.rds?raw=TRUE"
  download.file(url, "ames-liquor.rds", mode="wb")
}
data <- readRDS("ames-liquor.rds")
```

- Plot a scatterplot of lat and long of store locations.
- Provide a visual breakdown of the liquor category (by Category Name). Include volume sold in the breakdown. Make sure that all labels are readable.

I have written this code so far:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Latitude, y = Longitude))+
  geom_point(na.rm = TRUE)
```

however Im really confused

Comment: I don't see a Latitude or Longitude variable in that data set. I would start by looking at the `Store Location` column and breaking that into your coordinates. The `separate()` function can help there.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this on a small sample of the data. Let me know if this helps.

```
data <- readRDS("ames-liquor.rds")


library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
set.seed(123)
sample <- sample_n(data, size = 12000, replace = F)

new_data <- sample|>clean_names()

final_data <- new_data|>
  separate(col = store_location,
           into = c("x", "latitude", "longitude"), 
           sep = " ")|>
  select(category_name, latitude, longitude, volume_sold_liters)|>
  na.omit()

final_data$longitude = str_sub(final_data$longitude, end = -2)
final_data$latitude = str_sub(final_data$latitude, start = 2)

final_data$longitude = as.numeric(final_data$longitude)
final_data$latitude = as.numeric(final_data$latitude)
final_data$category_name = as_factor(final_data$category_name)

ggplot(final_data, aes(x = latitude, y = longitude)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab("LATITUDE (degrees)") +
  ylab("LONGITUDE (degrees)")

top_ten <- final_data|>
  group_by(category_name)|>
  summarise(total_volume = sum(volume_sold_liters))|>
  filter(total_volume > 2600)

ggplot(top_ten, aes(x = fct_reorder(category_name, total_volume), y = total_volume)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab("VOLUME SOLD (L)")
```

[image: scatter plot]
[image]

Comment: I got this error:

Comment: there is no package called ‘janitor’

Comment: You have to install first. You can install any package using `install.packages("<package name>")`. For eg, `install.packages("janitor")`.

Comment: I did it however I only get the first graph and not the volume one, I'm not sure why that happened.

Comment: Could you please share what you did?